# Pegar um item da RecyclerView e associar uma classe a outra

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

É o seguinte, estou fazendo um app para leitura de livros que vale como nota final, e quero fazer isso: depois de cadastrar um livro, gostaria de adicionar comentários do mesmo.
Ao tocar em um item da `recyclerview`, o *app* abre outra *activity*, para adicionar um comentário.

O problema é que ao adicionar mais de um livro, quando abre a *activity* de cadastro de comentários, ainda mostra o comentário do primeiro livro, e eu acho que daria certo pegando um item(livro) da `recyclerview` e associando ele ao comentário cadastrado. O problema é que não sei fazer isso. 
Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Obs.: Pra criar o banco de dados local, utilizo o *objectbox*.

Link do projeto
[Clique aqui](https://github.com/artur-auditore/Android-Projects/tree/master/BookMarker%20(nome%20temporario))

Comment: Deverá ter uma classe Comentario e a sua classe Livro deverá poder guardar uma lista de Comentario.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um Map pra referenciar as informações de acordo com o item da recycleview que você clicou e recuperar o valor através do get(Key), criando assim uma referência direta entre o item do recycleview e os comentários pertencentes a ela.

Ou então você pode puxar do banco juntando as duas informações Livro e seus comentários e no momento que você alimenta as views alimentar também os comentários.